# Is this typecasting? What is this?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-agnostic

Is this typecasting in C++ or am I seeing things?

```
    ((YesNoQuestion*)first)->setAnswer(false);
    ((MultipleAnswerQuestion*)second)->setAlternative(2, "City2");
    ((MultipleAnswerQuestion*)second)->setCorrectAlternative(2);
```

And why is this done instead of just

```
    first->setAnswer(false);
    second->setAlternative(2, "City2");
    second->setCorrectAlternative(2);
```

or

```
    ((YesNoQuestion)first)->setAnswer(false);
    ((MultipleAnswerQuestion)second)->setAlternative(2, "City2");
    ((MultipleAnswerQuestion)second)->setCorrectAlternative(2);
```

Doesn't the pointer provide the sufficient "identity" to make member functions of a child class viable for the parent class?

And why make the types pointers as well? Is it because the Question-objects are pointers that the new type has to be a pointer too?

---

Context:

These are answers from an old exam 5-6 years ago and everyone is on vacation now so I can't ask the professors who made it, but they did this in the main-file:

```
#include "MultipleAnswerQuestion.h"
#include "YesNoQuestion.h"

int main()
{
    Question *first = NULL;
    Question *second = NULL;

    string alt[] = {"City1", "City2", "City3"};
    first = new YesNoQuestion("Some statement here");
    second = new MultipleAnswerQuestion("Some question here", alt, 3, 0);

    ((YesNoQuestion*)first)->setAnswer(false);
    ((MultipleAnswerQuestion*)second)->setAlternative(2, "City2");
    ((MultipleAnswerQuestion*)second)->setCorrectAlternative(2);

    first->print(); //Prints Q
    second->print(); //Prints Q

}
```

**Abstract baseclass**: `Question(string question = "");`

**Children**:

```
YesNoQuestion(string question = "", bool answer = true);

MultipleAnswerQuestion(string question, string alternatives[], 
                       int nrOfAlternatives, int correctAnswer);
```

Comment: Seems to be a c-style upcast. The Question base class might not provide those members.

Comment: sidenote: in c++ it is better to use dynamic_cast as it actually does some checking

Comment: Another sidenote: this is a bad style C++.
1. Since C++11 you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.
2. Since C++11 you should use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers.
3. Even before C++11, there is missing `delete` (using `std::unique_ptr` removes the need for the `delete`).

Comment: _"everyone is on vacation now so I can't ask the professors who made it"_ Ask them when they're not on vacation?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit They're coming back a few days before an exam, but I need to know everything now so I can practice properly.

Comment: @GhostofBillGates: They're on holiday until a few days before an exam? That's horrendous!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Yeah, I've called them a few times and they said they'll return in a few days but the exam is in about a week, I guess what happened was that the ones responsible for this particular course went on vacation later, and this opportunity is a "second chance".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of type casting used for polymorphism. The first alternative you proposed would only work if the base class `Question` has virtual methods for `setAnswer`, `setAlternative` and `setCorrectAlternative`. If not, then you'd have to convert the pointer to the good class in order for the method to be found. The second alternative would not work because `first` and `second` are pointers, therefore their values are an addresses. Interpreting those addresses as objects of a class would not make sense in itself.

Comment: That answered all of my questions, tyvm.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on exactly how your classes are defined, but I'm guessing that your `Question` class does not have a `setAnswer` method that takes a bool.  And since `first` is a `Question` pointer, and not a `YesOrNoQuestion` pointer, then you can't call `YesOrNoQuestion` methods on it.

The fact that `first` actually points to a `YesOrNoQuestion` object is irrelevant, since the compiler must be able to determine at compile time whether a call is valid purely based on the type of the variable.

In your example, you can simply make `first` be a `YesOrNoQuestion` pointer to avoid the casting.  In more complex situations, it may not be that simple.

Answer (score 0):

`(Type*)` is often know as C-style casting, this basically choose one from: `const_cast`, `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`. I don't like the last one, so I would use one of them.

The reason the cast is done, is most likely because `Question` doesn't contain the methods which are being called. Why would a generic Question have a `setAnswer()` which accepts a bool?

In this case, I would have written something like the following:

```
YesNoQuestion *firstTyped = new YesNoQuestion("Some statement here");
MultipleAnswerQuestion *secondTyped = new MultipleAnswerQuestion("Some question here", alt, 3, 0);

Question *firstUntyped = firstTyped;
Question *secondUntyped = secondTyped;    

firstTyped->setAnswer(false);
secondTyped->setAlternative(2, "City2");
secondTyped->setCorrectAlternative(2);

firstUntyped->print(); //Prints Q
secondUntyped->print(); //Prints Q
```

Comment: _"Why would a generic Question have a setAnswer() which accepts a bool?"_ That it doesn't, and can't, means you can't use virtual dispatch, which means you need these hard-coded casts, which means your program design is fundamentally flawed. This scenario should never arise in the first place.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that is in the assumption that you use the Question object for this, while it could have a method `createEditor()` which could hide the need for `setAnswer()`